# Is there a way of creating a database in MYSQL without using SMO in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, smo

I'm trying to create a database through C# without using SMO, is it possible?! I've got this at the moment but I'm 99% it's wrong;

```
connectionString2 = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=master;" 
                            + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";"

this.OpenConnection(); //Which opens the above connection

// The Lines array has stored the sql statements to create the databse 
// and tables for that database 
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    create_database += line;
}
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(create_database, connection2);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

is it actually possible do this without using SMO?!

Comment: Not sure about what kind of dataabse server you're talking. SMO is MSSQL, but MySsqlCommand is MySQL...

Comment: Sorry Sascha, worded the title wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use MySqlCommand as you're doing in the example.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE YAYNEWDATABASE;", connection2);
connection2.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection2.Close();
```

Alternatively if you're going to be doing a lot of modification I'd suggest trying a tool like [Manatee](https://github.com/robconery/Manatee) to handle your database creation/migration as part of a build script.  This is making a lot of assumptions about what you're doing, but it doesn't hurt to be aware of it.

This adds migrations similar to those in rails to .net.

```
{
    up: "CREATE TABLE Orders (ID {pk}, OrderNumber {string} NOT NULL, SubTotal {money})",
    down: "DROP TABLE Orders"
}
```

Comment: Thanks sparks! I've already created and exported the database within an sql file, is there anyway to import this into some string variable  to create one long sql query?!

Comment: Not by default, but it shouldn't be that hard to do with some mysql commands.  You'd more or less run a foreach string in show tables describe table and substitute some of the data types for things like {string} and {pk} where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You might use something like this:

```
var connection = new MySqlConnection("Data Source=server;UserId=root;PWD=pass;");
var command = new MySqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE FancyDatabase;", connection);
connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Note: there is no default database, and you need to have the rights. And: this is untested code, uses standard sql features.